# No webdriver script working after selecting the calendar date

Tags: selenium-webdriver

No webdriver script working after selecting the calendar date.
On hover of date field inactive cursor comes. Is this inactive cursor creating any issue to move forward ?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer with your question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show your HTML and Code